# Gnome 3.10 ScreenCast + Audio on Arch

Tags: bash, arch-linux, gnome-shell, screencasting

I'm trying to record my desktop (including audio) in Gnome 3.10 on Arch Linux with the built-in screen recorder (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112473/audio-not-working-for-gnome-screencast-ctrl-alt-shift-r) post (and other similar solutions that can be found on the Internet), I've tried to apply the gconf settings

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.recorder pipeline "queue ! videorate ! vp8enc quality=10 speed=2 ! mux. pulsesrc ! audio/x-raw-int ! queue ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! mux. webmmux name=mux"
```

but I get the following error:

```
No such schema 'org.gnome.shell.recorder'
```

Browsing with `dconf-editor` I see that `org.gnome.shell.recorder` actually is not there and I couldn't find anything similar...
How can I record my desktop in gnome shell 3.10 including internal audio (not mic)?

**EDIT:** Also I would like not to include mouse cursor while recording.

Comment: I have the same problem with gnome 3.16 :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That key/schema was removed in `gnome-shell ≥ 3.10` so the solutions you found on the internet no longer work.
Ray Strode, gnome dev<sup>1</sup>:

> I've had a couple of people ask me if there's a way to do this in
>   gnome-shell 3.10 and later and I haven't had a good answer.  It's
>   complicated by the fact that g-s-d now handles starting things and the
>   org.gnome.shell.recorder schema has gone away.

Ray's suggestion there (assign a shortcut to that `gjs` command) is quite cool but his one liner is missing some `js` stuff. I had to replace the `%T` in `threads=%T` with a number (e.g. `2`) to make it work. Also, note the resulting `.webm` file name has no time stamp so subsequent runs will overwrite the existing one if you don't rename it. Finally, make sure your `XDG_VIDEOS_DIR` is defined in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` otherwise the command won't work (errors out with `cannot open output file`).
Anyway, back to your question, screen casting parameters are now hard-coded in gnome-shell ([`shell-recorder.c`](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/src/shell-recorder.c)) e.g.:

```
#define DEFAULT_PIPELINE "vp9enc min_quantizer=13 max_quantizer=13 cpu-used=5 deadline=1000000 threads=%T ! queue ! webmmux"
```

or

```
shell_recorder_init (ShellRecorder *recorder)
{
....
recorder->draw_cursor = TRUE;
```

and as far as I can tell, the only way to alter them would be via an extension like

[***EasyScreenCast***](https://iacopodeenosee.wordpress.com/projects/easyscreencast/)

(source code [here](https://github.com/iacopodeenosee/EasyScreenCast)) which allows you to customize all settings (including `draw-cursor`). It works fine, I only had to add my `gnome-shell` version e.g. `3.16.1` - to `metadata.json` and this custom `gstreamer` pipeline:

```
vp8enc  min_quantizer=10 max_quantizer=10 cpu-used=2 deadline=1000000  threads=2 ! queue ! mux. pulsesrc ! queue !  audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! queue ! mux. webmmux name=mux
```

via *Tweak-tool > Extensions > Easyscreencast > Screencast options*:

[image]

---

That aside, a trivial way to screencast + internal audio is via command line. All you need is to specify the input source for sound recording - either with `pacmd` (cli) or with `pavucontrol` (gui) and use `gst-launch` to record. So, first get the input source name ending with `.monitor` (that one can record audio from your sound card):

```
pacmd list-sources | sed -n 's/name: <\(.*\.monitor\)>/\1/p'
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
```

and then run:

```
pacmd set-default-source "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor"
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc ! videoconvert ! queue ! videorate ! vp8enc  min_quantizer=10 max_quantizer=10 cpu-used=2 deadline=1000000  threads=2 ! queue ! mux. pulsesrc ! queue !  audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! queue ! mux. webmmux name=mux ! filesink location=screencast.webm
```

To stop recording, switch back to terminal and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

---

<sup>1: [source](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=665548)</sup>

Comment: Great! Thanks you very much! basing on your answer, I have created as bash script for automate it. I'm posting it as an answer below just for everyone convenience.

Comment: i don't see anything related to extensions in gnome-tweaks on arch

Answer (score 3):

Based on don_crissti answer, I have created a bash script for automating this task.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "usage: screencast <outfile>"
    exit 1
fi

fname=$1
audio=$(pacmd list-sources | sed -n 's/\s*name: <\(.*\.monitor\)>/\1/p')

pacmd set-default-source "$audio"

echo "Screencast started, to stop it come back to terminal and hit ctrl+c..."

gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc \
    ! videoconvert \
    ! queue \
    ! videorate \
    ! vp8enc  min_quantizer=10 max_quantizer=10 cpu-used=2 deadline=1000000  threads=2 \
    ! queue \
    ! mux. pulsesrc \
    ! queue \
    !  audioconvert \
    ! vorbisenc \
    ! queue \
    ! mux. webmmux name=mux \
    ! filesink location=$fname > /dev/null

echo
echo "Screencast saved as $fname"
```

Usage:

```
$ ./screencast out_file_name.webm
```

All credits go to don_crissti. Please vote its answer!

Comment: doesn't work for me. i get an empty file.